# I couldn't make toggle

Tags: jquery

I couldn't make toggle search area. When I click the search button, there is no change. What is the problem? I am new to this issue.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".fa-search").click(function() {
    $(".searchform").toggle(1000);
    $(".searchform").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="search" method="get" class="searchform group" style="display: none;" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" id="deneme1">
  <input type="search" placeholder="
                           <?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" style="background-color:black; width:100%; min-height: 40px;" placeholder="Search" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>"
  />
  <span class="fa fa-search" style="float:right"></span>
  <style>
    .search {
      display: inline-block
    }
    /* prevent 100% width */
    
    .search .fa-search {
      left: auto;
      right: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</form>





<i class="shop-icon fa fa-search" style="margin-top: -48px; float:right; margin-right: 15px"></i>
```

Comment: What do you mean with toggle search area?

Comment: this is the third time you ask the same question the same way. This is not going to get better luck than the other two imho

Comment: @Wimanicesir when click on search button, search area must shown or hidden

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes but I need help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This snippet doesnt work , toggle function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68155356/this-snippet-doesnt-work-toggle-function)

Comment: @LelioFaieta no, there is no solution on that question for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".shop-icon").click(function() {
    $(".form-wrapper").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-wrapper hidden">
  <form role="search" method="get" class="searchform group" action="" id="deneme1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" value="" name="s" placeholder="Search" title="" />
    <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  </form>
</div>
<i class="shop-icon fa fa-search"></i>
```

Initially, there was so much styling that nothing would appear in your example. I cleared all the PHP and styling away. The code worked. I added a DIV to help target the form.